# How can i select checkboxes from the dynamically passed data?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: Check this image]

I want to implement an edit functionality. So, when I click on the edit option the user should be redirected to another page with the value entered previously.

I am getting value for all fields but unable to bind the radio buttons. Please help.

Comment: Post your code what you tried and also post how you are using dynamic data for check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> block1

```
        this.country.forEach(data1 =>{
                    if(this.country){
                        this.countryList.forEach(data => {
                            if (data.country_id == data1) {
                                data.checked = (!data.checked) ? true: false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
```

> block2

```
                this.mailTo.forEach(data1 =>{
                    this.userTypeList.forEach(data => {
                        if (data.cat_id == data1) {
                            data.checked = (!data.checked) ? true: false;
                        }
                    });
                })
```

Take two foreach one for the data that we are getting dynamically and the 2nd for each to select the checkboxes. Block1 is to select countries field and block2 is to select usertypes.